# SQL0206 Column or global variable P1 not found when inserting into DB2 table with SSIS

Tags: ssis, db2, ado.net, ibm-midrange, ssis-2016

Using SSIS 2016 data flow and inserting into DB2 table using the latest IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries .net connector. 
I'm able to preview the data, and SSIS grabs the column from the DB2 table and knows the type.

Table was created using:

```
create table MyLib.ADOTEST(Col1 integer)
```

Here is the table def:
[image: Using Ezview to show columns]

ADO Connection properties:
[image]
[image]

I can preview the data in the table (i manually added some records)

[image]

My dataflow is simple, script source that outputs 1 row with 1 INT Column

[image]

```
 public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.test = 100;
    }
```

Added a msgbox to show the value and type that is in the data flow:
[image]

[image]

AS400 error msg on my session:
[image]

This is the same error i get in SSIS:
[image]

I have no clue how to move on from here, I've tried everything i can think of. 
Happy to include any other info. I feel like there is a simple fix I just need a suggestion for something else to look at, anything please.

It does work when i run the insert from a script task using the following code:

```
using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries;

public void Main()
{
    // define the conn
    iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection("DataSource=MYAS400SERVER;UserID=MYUSERID; Password=myp@ssw0rd;Database=DB2RDBS;DefaultIsolationLevel=Chaos;Enlist=False;");

    // create a cmd
    iDB2Command cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    // set command type
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    // set command text
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into mylibrary.adotest values(88)";

    // open db2 connection
    conn.Open();

    // run the insert
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Also note this same connection works fine for Selecting data from this table.

Comment: What's the script in that Script Component? Have you checked to be sure the output is what you're expecting?

Comment: The script outputs a single record with 1 column, integer type, i get the same error regardless of source.

Comment: I updated the post to show the script output column and the script code

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the SSIS side of things but does it have a renaming property to the column? It looks like it is passing P1 to the insert statement and can't find the column on the IBM side it would need to be COL1 instead. Do all SSIS outputs go to P1,P2,etc?

Comment: @MichaelS.I've checked every property i can think of. The mapping shows COL1 the external columns show COL1, i have no clue how to even determine what statement is actually being sent.

Comment: I'm guessing MYLIB doesn't have auto journaling setup.

Comment: on the AS400 strsql    CREATE COLLECTION MYLIB    Then create the table in mylib    then it will magically work from external process.

Comment: @danny117 this might work using the OLE connection to not get the journaling error  but i still get the same P1 not found error after creating the collection from the SQL interface like you suggested and then creating the table in that collection.

Comment: If you do exactly the same, but write to SQL Server instead of DB2, does it work? I am wondering if there is actually a problem in the SSIS data flow, so that the SQL statement it is constructing is not what you expect.